# selenium web driver : not selecting value from dropdown, while there is value

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

I testing a web site by selenium. I have few dropdown there. All are working except one.
When i am manually clicking on the DropDown, it is showing more than one options there. But when i am printing the size of the Select item, it is showing that there is only 1 element. and Select by index is not working. I am thinking select by other options will not work, cause my select size showing only one. `https://test.dormbox.co/` the i am truing to test, its second step.

```
 Select pickupTime =
        new Select(
            driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//*[@id=\"v-register-step2\"]/div/div/div[4]/div/span/span/div/select")));
    WebElement pickup =
        driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//*[@id=\"v-register-step2\"]/div/div/div[4]/div/span/span/div/select"));
    pickup.click();
    System.out.println("Time Size : " + pickupTime.getAllSelectedOptions().size());
    try {
      pickupTime.selectByIndex(2);
      System.out.println("pickupTime : " + pickupTime.getAllSelectedOptions().get(0).getText());
      System.out.println(pickupTime.getAllSelectedOptions().get(0).getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have checked the x-path in browser. I am in Mozilla, Using JDK 8. Below are the maven dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: the dropdown is getting overlay by the chat which is displayed after some sort of time try to handle the chat box

Comment: @ Black Swan At least let us know whether the given answer is able to help you or not

Comment: @YaDav MaNish ur answer is helpful. just let me try it. i will back to u soon. upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
The below dropdowns is getting overlayed by the chatbox which gets 
appears after a couple of seconds later.

WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//select[@class='form-control  '])[2])"));
WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//select[@class='form-control  '])[3])"));
WebElement ele3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//select[@class='form-control  '])[4])"));

 //passing the reference of select type WebElement to the Select
 Select select2 = new Select(ele1);
 List<WebElement> selectAdd = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
 //you can check the proper xpath for the chatbox "svg "
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @class='drift-default-icon drift-default-icon--chat-round']"))).click();

 for(WebElement e : select2.getOptions()) {
            selectAdd.add(e);       
        }
System.out.println("Size is : "+selectAdd.size());


**Output:**
Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.101 
(af52a90bf87030dd1523486a1cd3ae25c5d76c9b-refs/branch- 
heads/4472@{#1462}) on port 4516
Only local connections are allowed.
INFO: Found exact CDP implementation for version 91

2021-06-07
2021-06-09
2021-06-11
2021-06-12
Size is : 5
```